# How can I remove all symbolic links with a special target?

Tags: wildcards, symlink, rm

With the command:

```
ls -la *
```

I can list all my symbolic links.

How can I remove all symbolic links which are linked to a special folder?

For example:

In my directory `usr/local/bin` I have the following entries:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50 Apr 22 14:52 allneeded -> /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/allneeded
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Apr 22 14:52 amstex -> /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/amstex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Apr 23 19:09 arara -> /home/marco/.arara/arara
```

Now I want to remove all links with the path `/usr/local/texlive/`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**Please make sure to read [the alternative answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39341/5462)**. It's even more to the point although not voted as high at this point.

You can use this to delete all symbolic links:

```
find -type l -delete
```

with modern `find` versions.

On older find versions it may have to be:

```
find -type l -exec rm {} \;
# or
find -type l -exec unlink {} \;
```

To limit to a certain link target, assuming none of the paths contain any newline character:

```
 find -type l | while IFS= read -r lnkname; do if [ "$(readlink '$lnkname')" == "/your/exact/path" ]; then rm -- "$lnkname"; fi; done
```

or nicely formatted

```
 find -type l |
 while IFS= read -r lnkname;
 do
   if [ "$(readlink '$lnkname')" = "/your/exact/path" ];
   then
     rm -- "$lnkname"
   fi
 done
```

The `if` could of course also include a more complex condition such as matching a pattern with `grep`.

---

Tailored to your case:

```
find -type l | while IFS= read -r lnk; do if (readlink "$lnk" | grep -q '^/usr/local/texlive/'); then rm "$lnk"; fi; done
```

or nicely formatted:

```
find -type l | while IFS= read -r lnk
do
  if readlink "$lnk" | grep -q '^/usr/local/texlive/'
  then
    rm "$lnk"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 45):

With a modern `find` that supports `-lname`:

```
find /usr/local/bin -lname '/usr/local/texlive/*' -delete
```

should do it.

Comment: Not even modern, necessarily.  GNU `find` has had `-lname` for longer than I have maintained it (since around 2003).

Comment: @JamesYoungman: Thanks! By modern `find` i really meant GNU `find`. ;) I used `usr/local/bin`, because that's what the OP used.

Answer (score 5):

The `find` solution is great.

Just in case your find doesn't support `-lname`, here's another way that uses only shell and `readlink`.

```
cd /usr/local/bin
for f in *; do
  case "$(readlink "$f")" in /usr/local/texlive/*)
    rm "$f"
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin(@e'{[[ $REPLY:P = /usr/local/texlive/* ]]}')
```

`$REPLY:P` fully resolves the path to a symlink-free one, so assuming `/usr/local/texlive` is symlink free itself, it would remove all files which after symlink resolution live under `/usr/local/textlive` which would include links to `/usr/local/texlive/foo` but also to `../texlive/bar` or to `/usr/./local/texlive/whatever` or to `/some/other/symlink` which is itself a symlink pointing in `/usr/local/texlive`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Go to path your and set yourself path configuration

```
ls -alh|grep "your-pattern-to-file-or-folder-for-symlink"| awk '{print $9}'|xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Since these are paths like `usr/local/bin` that `grep` is searching for , `grep -E` is the way to go. Otherwise there would be no matching results. Also `h` in `ls` doesn't serve any purpose here! `-h, --human-readable : with -l, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)` . For more see `man ls` or `man grep`

Answer (score -2):

`sudo unlink /path/of/your/package`

thats it

Comment: How does this remove all symbolic links pointing to targets beneath the given path?  Note that the question asks about removing the symbolic links in a particular directory that points to targets in some other directory.